# Smooth cuts on small ceramic tile

Tags: ceramic-tile

I am going to be installing some 2” x 4” mosaic tile sheets in my bathroom. What would be the best method to cut the tile edges to size? Would a score and snap cutter give the cleanest edge?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cut those size tiles using a glass cutter to score them and then snapping them by laying them across a pencil at the score mark, then just pressing down on both ends. It made very clean cuts.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a wet saw. The least expensive one at home centers is around $70. That will give you clean cuts. Scoring and snapping has always been stressful for me because some would not break cleanly and I would be worried about running out of tile. I would only put score and break cuts at the edges where they are covered up (floor tiles). When mounted on a wall where the cuts are visible, I would definitely recommend a wet saw.

Comment: Some locations have rental use as well.